# Override window function fbq initialized by facebook pixel

Tags: javascript, facebook-pixel

I have web site with many fbq calls and want to override all of them from google tag manager

```
<script>
  //this snippet is in the page source and I don't have access to change it
  !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
  {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
  n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
  if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
  n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
  t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
  'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
  fbq('init', 'XXX');
  fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>

<script>
  //this one in google tag manager
  var origFbq = window.fbq;
  window.fbq = function(action, event, params) {
    params = params || {};
    if(action == 'track') {
      console.log(action, event, params);
    }
    origFbq(action, event, params);  
  };
</script>
```

It works for me as I receive console messages
But at the same time I receive error

> fbevents.js:25 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of
> undefined
> at qa (fbevents.js:25)

And data are not sent to facebook. Which can be seen in facebook pixel helper

How can I override fbq function to have console messages and proper fbq function calls?